# Razor SQL - Update statement using variable as column name dynamic statement translation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic-sql

The reason of this is an internal application for a few users, no need for security.

I've seen a lot of post about the subject in SQL, but I can't translate it in Razor.

I'm trying to make an Update Statement in Razor where the column is selected by the user.

How can I translate this into a dynamic statement? Like Exec() or sp_executesql

```
if(IsPost){
    NoEmpl = Request.Form["NoEmpl"];
    NoCam = Request.Form["NoCam"];
    Day = Request.Form["Day"];
    Date = Request.Form["Date"];
    var db = Database.Open("Schedule");
    var insertCommand = "UPDATE AtiTruck SET " + NoCam + "=@0 WHERE Day=@1 AND Date >= @2"; 
    db.Execute(insertCommand, NoEmpl, Day, Date);}
```

The `SET NoCam` is selected with the NoCam form input... Its value must be filled with the NoEmpl (=@0) form input.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do any updating in a Razor cshtml page... All your updating should be done in the Controllers or a DataAccess Layer. This way you can verify the user data to ensure valid data goes into the database.

Comment: Rule number 1 for web development... Never trust data from a user input. A user can always manipulate the data.

Comment: All trusted user... Don't worry

Comment: Ok... then at first glance your SQL is incorrect. It looks like your @1 is pointing to NoEmpl but in the SQL it is "WHERE Day=@1"... I assume that Day should point to @2 and Date should be @3... The sequence of your parameters is NoTruck = @0, NoEmpl = @1, Day = @2, Date = @3

Comment: Yea.. I was trying to explain my needs. I did this statement and it seems pretty close.
`var insertCommand = "UPDATE AtiCamion SET " + NoCam + "=@0 WHERE Day=@1 AND Date >= @2";
db.Execute(insertCommand, NoCam, NoEmpl, Day, Date);`
I now have the error in the db.execute line. It says that the token "3279" is in error. What is good is that 3279 is the result of the request form for the "NoCam" var. But I don't know how to create the execute correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out without using Exec() or sp_sp_executesql

```
var insertCommand = "UPDATE AtiCamion SET " + NoCam + "=@1 WHERE Day=@2 AND Date >= @3"; 
db.Execute(insertCommand, "NoCam", NoEmpl, Day, Date);
```

I think I was looking too far

Thank you